# Getting different JWT tokens with the same key

Tags: cakephp, jwt

I am new to the JWT tokens, and I am trying get information from a jwt token. The thing is I don't have issues when I am the one generating the token, but, for some reason, when I generate the token at [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/) with exactly the same information, the token is different and, therefore, the validation fails. I guess the problem may come from the key I am using, as, when using a simple key like "HELLO", this disparity does not happen. This is my code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class JWTComponent extends Component
{
    public function check_token($token){
        $decoded = [];
         $key = openssl_pkey_get_details(openssl_pkey_get_private('file://'.APP.'private.pem'))['key'];
       
        try {
            $decoded = JWT::decode($token, $key, array('HS256'));
            $decoded = (array) $decoded;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $decoded = ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
        }finally{
            return $decoded;
        }
    }

    public function get_token($data) {
        $key = openssl_pkey_get_details(openssl_pkey_get_private('file://'.APP.'private.pem'))['key'];
        return JWT::encode($data, $key);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the token is different". Can you please add the token you created by code and the one created on jwt.io? Also i see you load a private.pem, so probably a RSA key, but then you pass `HS256` as algorithm parameter to the decode function. This is probably wrong. I guess it's supposed to be `RS256`. And then you would also need the public key for verification, the private is used for signing. All this is just guessing, because the relevant information is missing in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is good. The integrity of the token is verified by checking the signature. Tokens are signed by the party which issued them. You can use different algorithms to sign those tokens. As @jps pointed out you can have symmetric and asymmetric signing. In symmetric signing the same key is used to sign and verify the key. `HS256` is a symmetric signing algorithm. You can use a certificate to do that (like in your code), but it's a bit of an overkill in my opinion. Anyway, if you want the key generated at JWT.io to be valid in your code, you will have to paste the private key in JWT.io so that it can be used for signing. Then the token should be valid in your code. That's why it worked when you used a simple string as the key.

The token that you generate in your code and in JWT.io can, in the end, look a bit differently. That is, they will both be long strings, with three parts separated by dots, but the strings does not have to be equal. This does not mean that this is a different token. The encoded JWT can differ depending on whether you used line breaks in the input, or how many spaces you used. Even though, the encoded final JWTs may look differently, these tokens have still the same value. If you decode them, you will get the same JSON, maybe slightly differently formatted.

As for the use of the symmetric algorithm, it's usually better to use asymmetric signing, so if you are able to go with that option I would definitely recommend it. Also, have a look at some libraries for PHP to issue and validate JWT, unless you write the code to learn more about JWT itself. You can find a list of libraries on [JWT.io](https://jwt.io).

If you're planning to secure your APIs with JWTs, have a look at this [security best practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/) article I wrote, to learn about the dos and don'ts of JWTs.

Comment: *The encoded JWT can differ depending on whether you used line breaks in the input, or how many spaces you used* - that should make no difference, because jwt.io and all jwt libs strip all whitespace. Take the encoded payload of a JWT generated on jwt.io and decode it on https://www.base64decode.org, you'll see just a single line without whitespace.

Comment: It does make a difference if the library you use doesn't do that. I will not risk saying that each and every JWT library out there does strip the header and payload of whitespace and line breaks.